# How to delete array element from json in case of rest api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am coding to build a contact app. For this I am using Angular and storing contacts information in json and accessing it using rest API. Every time I delete one particular contact, everything gets deleted except id of that contact object.I want to remove that whole contact object.

Json:

```
"contacts": [
 {
 "gender": "male",
 "name": {
"title": "mr",
"first": "hugh",
"last": "garcia"
 },
 "location": {
"street": "8196 queensway",
"city": "bradford",
"state": "oxfordshire",
"postcode": "R0 1SL"
 },
"email": "hugh.garcia@example.com",
"dob": "1989-12-13 19:53:47",
"registered": "2014-03-23 22:55:37",
"phone": "016977 4973",
"cell": "0763-260-228",     
"id": 1,
"nat": "GB"
},
{...},
{...}

]
```

After deleting it looks like this:

```
 "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {...},
    {...}
    ]
```

my html for deleting which contains delete button for each contact in view.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl1 as c1">

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="contact in c1.contacts" ng-click="c1.selectContact($index);">
            <b>Name:</b>{{contact.name.first+" "+contact.name.last}}
            <button ng-show="c1.deleteFlag" style="float: right;" ng-click="c1.delete($index)">delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

 </div>
```

my controller code:

```
(function (){
    var module=angular.module("module1");

    module.controller("MyCtrl1", function (Contacts) {

    var self=this;

    this.delete=function (index) {
    var userData={};
    Contacts.deleteUser(index, userData)
    .then(function () {
        console.log("");
     })

    }


 })();
```

my service code:

```
(function(){

    module.service("Contacts",dataObjects);

    var module=angular.module("module1");

    function dataObjects($http) {

    var self=this;

    self.deleteUser=function (index,userData) {
    index++;
    return $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/'+index,userData)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
 })();
```

Comment: you are doing a PUT operation. Doesn't look like a DELETE to me

Comment: yes i thought by putting empty object we can delete it, can you tell me how to delete it over rest api

Comment: I don't know which database you are using